# How to properly position elements on a full sized fixed background? - for different resolutions

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I have a background image which is fixed at the pages resolution this uses jquery to automatically re-size based on a user's monitor resolution. This is working great, however I know what to add two div's on top which will be transparent containing HREF's hovering over two parts of the background image. When I create the two div's I have given them a position of absolute and then the container they are in a position of relative. However when I change screen resolution the div's change position.

**html:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {    

    var theWindow        = $(window),
        $bg              = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {

        if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgwidth');
        }

    }

    theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <img src="images/image.png" id="bg" alt="">
    <a id="company-procedures-link" href=""></a>
    <a id="company-documents-link" href=""></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }

#container{
position:relative;
width:100%
height:100%
}

#procedures-link{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20em;
    left: 50em;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid;
}

#documents-link{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20em;
    left: 50em;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

is there a better way to achieve this? or am I incorrectly using the positioning?

Many Thanks

Comment: They would since you are using em which is a relative unit. If you want the position the same no matter what the resolution is then use px.

Comment: It is not clear where you want to put links on different size screens, can you describe? Probably you need to set left/top with percent values like `top:50%;`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to use [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size), but it is not supported by IE8 and below.

```
body {
  background:url(images/image.png) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, I have changed to pixel values for the positioning and now it is working across different resolutions. setting a top & left value of 50% makes the image appear halfway down the page with a white background. The background cover works well. Is there a way to make the elements position absolutely when the browser window is re-sized by the user? at the moment the elements do not conform to the background image. perhaps this is not possible? Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried values in percents (like 50%) for elements top/left?